# C++ Opencv Rescale Bounding Rect

Tags: android, c++, opencv

So, I have a problem:

Im doing opencv in android and, since images that im taking with my phone are of very high resolution, I want to resize image to smaller ones, get contours and process the image, and then, create bounding rect on the original image. For that, I would need to scale that bounding box so it perfectly fits my original image. The code I have is working very well with the processing and drawing bounding box on the original image, but, how to do scaling? Here is the code snippet:

```
 Mat &image = *(Mat *) matAddrRgba;
//over here I should resize image and do the processing with the resized one, and in the end, scale everything back so I can draw the bounding box to the original
    Rect bounding_rect;

    Mat thr(image.rows, image.cols, CV_8UC1);
    cvtColor(image, thr, CV_BGR2GRAY); //Convert to gray
    threshold(thr, thr, 150, 255, THRESH_BINARY + THRESH_OTSU); //Threshold the gray

    vector<vector<Point> > contours; // Vector for storing contour
    vector<Vec4i> hierarchy;
    RotatedRect rect;
    findContours(thr, contours, hierarchy, CV_RETR_CCOMP,
                 CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE); // Find the contours in the image
    sort(contours.begin(), contours.end(),
         compareContourAreas);            //Store the index of largest contour
    bounding_rect = boundingRect(contours[0]);
    rect = minAreaRect(contours[0]);
    // matrices we'll use
    Mat rot_mat, rotated;
    // get angle and size from the bounding box
    float angle = rect.angle;
    Size rect_size = rect.size;

    if (rect.angle < -45.) {
        angle += 90.0;
        swap(rect_size.width, rect_size.height);
    }

    rot_mat = getRotationMatrix2D(rect.center, angle, 1);

    warpAffine(image, rotated, rot_mat, image.size(), INTER_CUBIC);

    image = rotated;

    cvtColor(image, thr, CV_BGR2GRAY); //Convert to gray
    threshold(thr, thr, 150, 255, THRESH_BINARY + THRESH_OTSU); //Threshold the gray

    findContours(thr, contours, hierarchy, CV_RETR_CCOMP, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);
    sort(contours.begin(), contours.end(), compareContourAreas);
    bounding_rect = boundingRect(contours[0]);

    image = Mat(image, bounding_rect);
```

Comment: "how to do scaling" -- Unless that refers to climbing or removing of scales from objects, then *multiplication* tends to do the trick. You could add an offset of `scale-1` to the new width and height to make it fit a little better. Just take a piece of square paper and draw it -- this shouldn't take much work to figure out.

Comment: @DanMašek I get the rotated rect that is the product of my calculations. I then rotate image to get it perfectly aligned with my device. After that I do crop with that rotated rect(creating bounding rect from it). How to extend/multiply/enlarge that bounding rect?

Comment: For example, if you double the width and height of an image, then the same scaling factors applies to coordinates. So the x and y coordinates of bounding box would double, it's width and height would double.

Comment: @DanMašek Is there any way to enlarge bounding box from center, so, lets say, double the width and height, but leave center where it is?

Comment: Imagine you have a bounding box at (0,0) with dimensions (2,4). The center is therefore at (1,2). | Now we double the size of the bounding box, so its new dimensions are (4,8). This puts the new center at (2,4). The offset of the new center from old center is (1, 2). Therefore for the centers to match, we have to offset the position of the bounding box to (-1, -2). | I really suggest you try to work these out with a piece of square or graph paper, to help you visualize it.

Comment: @DanMašek yea, you right, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so, I would start with this:

```
    Mat &img = (Mat ) matAddrRgba;
    Mat image;
    double thrA = 5;
    resize(img, image, Size((int) (img.size().width / thrA), (int) (img.size().height / thrA)));

    Rect bounding_rect;

    Mat thr(image.rows, image.cols, CV_8UC1);
    cvtColor(image, thr, CV_BGR2GRAY); //Convert to gray
    threshold(thr, thr, 150, 255, THRESH_BINARY + THRESH_OTSU); //Threshold the gray

    vector<vector<Point> > contours; // Vector for storing contour
    vector<Vec4i> hierarchy;
    RotatedRect rect;
    findContours(thr, contours, hierarchy, CV_RETR_CCOMP,
                 CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE); // Find the contours in the image
    sort(contours.begin(), contours.end(),
         compareContourAreas);            //Store the index of largest contour
    bounding_rect = boundingRect(contours[0]);

    bounding_rect.width = (int) (bounding_rect.width * thrA);
    bounding_rect.height = (int) (bounding_rect.height * thrA);
    bounding_rect.x = (int) (bounding_rect.x * thrA);
    bounding_rect.y = (int) (bounding_rect.y * thrA);

    rectangle(img, bounding_rect, Scalar(0, 172, 236, 255), 3);
```

As you can see, you should have a scale, that scale should be multiplied with width, height, x and y of the bounding rect. You can figure out the rest from this.